# Ubuntu *refuses* to access samba share from windows 10 server machine - Not Authorized

Tags: networking, windows, printing, samba

I've ruled out all firewall issues on both devices, the share itself can be seen under "WORKGROUP" from the ubuntu device. The issue is despite password sharing and all related gate-keeping settings turned off on windows 10, anything related to accessing "workgroup" on the ubuntu machine results in nagging about credentials, except the admin credentials for the windows machine don't work, blanks don't work. WORKGROUP is listed correctly and is verified as called "WORKGROUP".

Searching I found almost all advise is for the opposite use, windows unable to access linux samba...

(This is for a printer hosted via USB on the windows machine, however browsing via gnome or the add printer advanced settings page results in same behavior. Credentials simply don't work)

Answer (score 0):

Try with smbclient:

```
smbclient //windows10host/sharename -U username
```

Then iterate that command with different values for -m, specifying a different protocol:

- NT1
- SMB2
- SMB3

If it works with one or more of these, but not another, then you may have to change some defaults in `/etc/samba/smb.conf` via `client min protocol` and/or `client max protocol`. See the `smb.conf(5)` manpage for details.